# period of the antiderivative of a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f$ be bounded and Riemann integrable function on any bounded interval and $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(x)\,dx$$
And let $F$ and $f$ both be periodic functions Where $a$ is the period of $F$. Does it imply that the $a$ is also the period (not necessary the lowest) of $f$

To show it I thought that:
Meanwhile the conditions let us to apply the Fundamental theorem of calculus

We have $$(F(x)-F(x+a))'= f(x)-f(x+a)=0$$
$$f(x)=f(x+a)$$

Is it a right reasoning?

Comment: Yeah, I see no problem with your answer.

Comment: thanks for reply @Bubbly_and_cozy

Comment: I think you need that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. What you seem to be asking is if the *derivative* of a periodic function $F$ is again periodic.

Comment: @Blitzer yes that’s one of the conditions of the FTC

Comment: @Blitzer thank you for the comment. extended FTC doesn't require continuity but require piecewise continuity. and if $f$ if bounded and Riemann integrable on bounded interval it is piecewise continuous (or almost continuous)

Comment: @MartinR not actually. F and f both periodic. it is given/ I need to show they have comon period, or the period of F appear to being the period of the f

Comment: The answer to the question in your first paragraph is "yes". The title (implicitly) asks a different question, to which the answer is "no", and the reasoning of your argument is a bit jumbled, and almost looks like you are assuming the thing you're trying to prove.

Comment: Let $g(0)=f(0)+1$ and $g(x)=f(x), $ $x\neq 0.$ Then $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ cannot be simultaneously periodic. But $G(x)=F(x).$

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I am not a native english speaker may be I missing something. What is the I am interested in  in to show the period of F $a$ is also period of f

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I dont need to show that antiderivative of f is periodic/ It is already given

Comment: Please anybody native english speaker help me with the title))

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. Antiderivatives of $f$ and $g$ are equal, but $f$ and $g$ cannot be simultaneously periodic.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I appreciate your comments but what is effect of this on my proof. since it is given that f is periodic function

Comment: Sorry I made some changes on the text. May be it is clear now??

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked the assumption that besides $F$ also $f$ is periodic.

Comment: Let $F(x)=\sin x$ and $f(x)=\cos x$ for $x\neq 4k\pi$ and $f(4k\pi)=0.$ Then $f$ has period $4\pi$ while $F$ has period $2\pi.$

Comment: thank you @RyszardSzwarc very composite counterexample I need time to study it)

Comment: Developing on Ryszard Szwarc comment: choose $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \Bbb Z$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$ which has every posible period, but $f$ has (minimal) period $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing on the comments it seems natural to assume that $f$ is continuous. What follows is not a direct answer to the OP question, but is closely related to it, in my opinion.

Let $F$ and $f$ be periodic, where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f.$ With no loss of generality we may assume that $F(0)=0.$ Let $a$ be the minimal period of $F.$  We will restrict to the nontrivial case $a>0.$ Then $f$ has period $a.$ ***The question arises, whether $a$ is the minimal period of $f.$*** Assume by contradicton that $b$ is the minimal period of $f$ and $0<b<a.$ Then $a=nb$ for a natural number $n\ge 2.$

We have $$\displaylines{0=F(0)=F(a)=\int\limits_0^af(t)\,dt = \sum_{k=1}^n \int\limits_{(k-1)b}^{kb}f(t)\,dt\\
 =\sum_{k=1}^n \int\limits_{0}^{b}f(t)\,dt=n\int\limits_{0}^{b}f(t)\,dt}$$
Therefore $$\int\limits_0^bf(t)\,dt =0$$
As $f$ has period $b$ we get
$$0=\int\limits_0^bf(t)\,dt=\int\limits_x^{x+b}f(t)\,dt =F(x+b)-F(x)$$
which implies that $F$ has period $b,$ a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you @Ryszard for the answer and for the great effort